# Can't login to Tomcat 8 Manager

Tags: tomcat

I have installed Tomcat 8.5.24 on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 as described in the following article: [How To Install Apache Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I can access to Tomcat when typing `localhost:8080` everything appears to be installed correctly. But I can't access the Tomcat Manager.

Here is my `tomcat-users.xml` file:

```
<tomcat-users xmlns="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tomcat.apache.org/xml tomcat-users.xsd"
          version="1.0">

    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>

    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
    <user username="maven-deployer" password="maven" roles="manager-script"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

And this is the configuration of the `server.xml` file:

```
...
<GlobalNamingResources>

    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
</GlobalNamingResources>

...

<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
    ...
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
    </Realm>
    ...
</Engine>
```

The problem is that I can't login when I enter username `admin` and password `admin` an empty login prompt shows up again. I have inspected the logs files but there is nothing there.

I have searched on google for this issue and I have tried everything but nothing works.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

1- Following the mentioned tutorial I created a tomcat group and a tomcat user:

```
> sudo groupadd tomcat
> sudo useradd -s /bin/false -g tomcat -d /usr/local/tomcat tomcat
```

2- Then I gave the tomcat group ownership over the entire installation directory:

```
> sudo chgrp -R tomcat /usr/local/tomcat
```

3- Next I gave tomcat group access and execute access to conf directory:

```
> sudo chmod -R g+r conf
> sudo chmod g+x conf
```

4- And finally I made tomcat user owner of the webapps, work, temp and logs directories:

```
> sudo chown -R tomcat webapps/ work/ temp/ logs/
```

But when I was having to access the `tomcat-users.xml` file, I added myself to the tomcat group:

```
> sudo usermod -a -G tomcat karim
```

Then I edited this file, saved and closed with:

```
> sudo kate /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
```

But I could not log into Tomcat Manager. After repeating steps 1, 2, 3 and 4, I logged in successfully, can somebody explain what happened?